# Why is bidet pronounced with a "day" and what is the correct pronunciation of the word sentient?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

(Struggling with self-doubt, would appreciate some help from you English aficionados)

Why is bidet not pronounced as "bi-det"? Also, is sentient pronounced as "sen-ti-ent" or "sen(t)SH(ē)ənt"? Yesterday, I pronounced anathema as "anna-thema" I actually had to google it! My pronunciation has gone to shit over the last year and a half. I plan on going all the way back to the basics to remedy this.

P.S. I use Ebonics, and I've been dabbling in learning how to speak and read in Spanish and French which may be the cause of my issue.

Comment: All of these words can be looked up in a dictionary for pronunciation advice.

Answer (score 1):

Bidet is French in origin. It is still pronounced using French rules (roughly bee-day). See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidet.

Sentient is Latin in origin. See http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sentient. It can have either pronunciation you state. See 
https://youtu.be/L2WWAQSSAVs

Although there is an answer to the question of each individual word's pronunciation, English has taken words from so many sources that the rules are not all consistent. It's interesting to see where the pronunciation comes from, but sometimes it comes down to learning and memorizing.

Comment: One overly simplistic rule for French-derived terms is to pronounce all the letters, except DO NOT pronounce the very last letter, whatever it is.  (Works maybe 75% of the time.)

Comment: That "so" in your first sentence is a nonsequitur.  There are many French-derived terms that aren't pronounced in a French way ("cadet", "lucre", "ogre") or that are pronounced in a French way only in some dialects or by some speakers ("lingerie", "garage", "grandeur", "niche").

Comment: Good point rjpond. I edited the answer.

Comment: @rjpond Is _lingerie_ ever pronounced in a non-French-imitative way? I’ve never heard that. Is it a geographical thing (and if so, where)?

Comment: @HotLicks And also don’t expect sequences of multiple vowels to make too much sense (_beau_ /oʊ/, _croissant_ /wa/, _lieu_ /(j)uː/, etc.).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet In AmE it is rarely pronounced in a French-imitative way.  AmE speakers usually pronounce the final "ie" as "ay", instead of "ee".  Of course, English "ay" is an acceptable approximation for French "é" /e/, but is hard to see why "ay" should be considered an acceptable approximation for "i(e)" /i/.  So "lingerie" falls into a strange category of words that people think they are pronouncing in the French way but they're actually not.

Comment: @rjpond That is still a French-imitative way, just one that’s not necessarily very faithful to the original—any pronunciation that has a nasalised vowel will be imitative of something foreign. It’s only _imitative_ of French, after all, not actual French. I thought you meant that there are people who pronounce it /ˈlinʤəri/, to rhyme with _gingery_, which I’ve never heard.

Comment: Among the most important, most consistent and easiest to learn supplements to @HotLicks' rule are (1) always pronounce accented é, even when final ("café", "fiancé", "résumé", "cliché") and (2) pronounce "ch" soft like "sh" ("cliché", "papier-mâché", "chef").